# How to load Data to imageView, after refresh of recycvlerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerViews, which represent my grocery list. 
When I click on an item it gets "transferred" to the other list. 
The problem is that the images are loaded with Glide and Firebase Storage and they don't show the correct images even if the listitem does not have a path.

I have tried every notifyDataSetChanged(), recyclerView.notifyItemChanged() and recyclerView.invalidate() and others. Maybe you could help me.

This is my Adapter:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapterEinkaufslisteDetail(
    val context: Context,
    val lebensmittelList: ArrayList<Inventarstueck>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterEinkaufslisteDetail.ViewHolder>() {




    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewAdapterEinkaufslisteDetail.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.


        //Es wird der Name, die Anzahl, die Einheit (gramm, kg, etc) das Bild und ein Warnzeichen angezeigt, falls ein Produkt abläufty
        holder.mName.text = lebensmittelList[position].name_de.toString()


        val array = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.einheit_kurz)


        val placeholder =
            lebensmittelList[position].restlichemenge.toString() + " " + array[lebensmittelList[position].einheit!!]




        holder.mAnzahl.text = placeholder
        //   holder.txtTitle.text = userList[position]

        holder.mZeichen.visibility = View.INVISIBLE


        //KLEINEs Anzeigebild der Produkte runterladen

        if (!(lebensmittelList[position].fotoURL.isNullOrEmpty() || lebensmittelList[position].fotoURL.isNullOrBlank())) {

            //Überprüfen, ob im Feld die Endung gespeichert ist, wenn nicht, immer png!!
            val url:String
            if(lebensmittelList[position].fotoURL!!.endsWith(".png")){
                url = lebensmittelList[position].fotoURL!!
            }else{
                url = lebensmittelList[position].fotoURL + ".png"
            }

            val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
            val storageRef = storage.reference
            // Points to "images"
            val imagesRef = storageRef.child(Constants.FIREBASE_STORAGE_PRODUKTFOTO_KLEIN_PFAD)
            val fotoRef = imagesRef.child(url)

            GlideApp.with(this.context).load(fotoRef).into(holder.mProduktfoto)

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return lebensmittelList.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewAdapterEinkaufslisteDetail.ViewHolder {

        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_inventar, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)

    }


    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this)
        }




        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            clickListener!!.onItemClick(adapterPosition, v);
        }

        override fun onLongClick(v: View): Boolean {
            clickListener!!.onItemLongClick(adapterPosition, v)
            return true
        }

        val mName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rvInventar_tv_Produktname)
        val mAnzahl = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rvInventar_tv_Anzahl)
        val mProduktfoto = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.rvInventarProduktFoto)
       val mZeichen = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.rvInventar_Icon)
        //  val txtTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtTitle)
        val mCard = itemView.findViewById<MaterialCardView>(R.id.rvCardInventar)



    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(clickListener: ClickListener) {
        RecyclerViewAdapterEinkaufslisteDetail.clickListener = clickListener
    }
    interface ClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int, v: View)
        fun onItemLongClick(position: Int, v: View)

    }

    companion object {
        private var clickListener: RecyclerViewAdapterEinkaufslisteDetail.ClickListener? = null
    }
}
```

This is where I change the data:

```
   rvKaufen = findViewById(R.id.rvEinkaufslisteDetailKaufen)
        val layoutmanager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
        rvKaufen.layoutManager = layoutmanager


        rvGekauft = findViewById(R.id.rvEinkaufslisteDetailGekauft)
        val layoutmanager2 = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)
        rvGekauft.layoutManager = layoutmanager2


        rvadapter = RecyclerViewAdapterEinkaufslisteDetail(this, itemsInEinkaufsliste)
        //  val rvadapter = RecyclerViewAdapterInventar(this.context!!, lebensmittelliste)
        rvadapterGekauft = RecyclerViewAdapterEinkaufslisteDetail(this, itemsGekauft)


        //nur einmal itemclicklistener zuweisen, sonst megafehler! intern abrufen aus welchem Recyclerview der Click gekommen ist
/**/   rvadapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : RecyclerViewAdapterEinkaufslisteDetail.ClickListener {
            override fun onItemClick(position: Int, v: View) {
                Log.d("Click", "onItemClick position: $position")
                val parentId = (v.parent as View).id
                if (parentId == rvKaufen.id) {

                    Toast.makeText(this@EinkaufslisteDetail, "GeKAUFt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    /*  val inventarstueck = rvadapter.lebensmittelList[position].copy()


                     //Hier auch aus den Listen löschen??
                     //TODO
                    rvadapterGekauft.lebensmittelList.add(inventarstueck)
                     rvadapterGekauft.notifyDataSetChanged()

                     rvadapter.lebensmittelList.removeAt(position)

                   //  itemsInEinkaufsliste.removeAt(position)
                     rvadapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)

                     //  rvadapter.lebensmittelList.removeAt(position)
                     */
                    //rvadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    val inventarstueck = itemsInEinkaufsliste[position].copy()
                    //itemsGekauft.add(inventarstueck)
                    itemsGekauft.add(inventarstueck)
                    rvadapterGekauft.notifyItemInserted(itemsGekauft.size-1)

                   // rvadapterGekauft.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,itemsGekauft.size)


                    itemsInEinkaufsliste.removeAt(position)
                    rvadapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)




                    rvadapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position,itemsInEinkaufsliste.size)


             /*       rvKaufen.adapter = null
                    rvKaufen.layoutManager = null
                    rvKaufen.adapter = rvadapter
                    val layoutmanager3 = GridLayoutManager(this@EinkaufslisteDetail, 3)
                    rvKaufen.layoutManager = layoutmanager3

                    rvadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    //rvKaufen.removeViewAt(position)
                   // rvGekauft.add
                    rvGekauft.adapter = null
                    rvGekauft.layoutManager = null
                    rvGekauft.adapter = rvadapterGekauft
                    val layoutmanager4 = GridLayoutManager(this@EinkaufslisteDetail, 3)
                    rvKaufen.layoutManager = layoutmanager4

                    rvadapterGekauft.notifyDataSetChanged()*/

                } else if (parentId == rvGekauft.id) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@EinkaufslisteDetail, "Zurück geschoben", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                   /* val inventarstueck = rvadapterGekauft.lebensmittelList[position].copy()

                    rvadapter.lebensmittelList.add(inventarstueck)
                    rvadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    rvadapterGekauft.lebensmittelList.removeAt(position)
                    rvadapterGekauft.notifyItemRemoved(position)*/


                    val inventarstueck = itemsGekauft[position].copy()
                    //itemsGekauft.add(inventarstueck)
                    itemsInEinkaufsliste.add(inventarstueck)
                    rvadapter.notifyItemInserted(itemsInEinkaufsliste.size-1)


                   // rvadapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,itemsInEinkaufsliste.size)


                    itemsGekauft.removeAt(position)
                    rvadapterGekauft.notifyItemRemoved(position)


                    rvadapterGekauft.notifyItemRangeChanged(position,itemsGekauft.size)






                 /*   rvKaufen.adapter = null
                    rvKaufen.layoutManager = null
                    rvKaufen.adapter = rvadapter
                    val layoutmanager3 = GridLayoutManager(this@EinkaufslisteDetail, 3)
                    rvKaufen.layoutManager = layoutmanager3

                    rvadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()



                    rvGekauft.adapter = null
                    rvGekauft.layoutManager = null
                    rvGekauft.adapter = rvadapterGekauft
                    val layoutmanager4 = GridLayoutManager(this@EinkaufslisteDetail, 3)
                    rvKaufen.layoutManager = layoutmanager4

                    rvadapterGekauft.notifyDataSetChanged()*/
                }


            }

            override fun onItemLongClick(position: Int, v: View) {
                Log.d("Click", "onItemLongClick pos = $position")
                Log.d("Click", "onItemClick position: $position")
                val parentId = (v.parent as View).id
                if (parentId == rvKaufen.id) {

                    Toast.makeText(this@EinkaufslisteDetail, "Verändern", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    val inventarstueck = rvadapter.lebensmittelList[position].copy()
                    val intent = Intent(this@EinkaufslisteDetail, EinkaufslisteProduktBearbeiten::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("swissID",inventarstueck.swiss_id)
                    intent.putExtra("scandatum",inventarstueck.scandatum)
                    intent.putExtra("einkaufslistenID",einkaufslistenID)
                    startActivityForResult(intent,_resultCODE)

                }else if (parentId == rvGekauft.id) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@EinkaufslisteDetail, "Keine Aktion möglich", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }


            }
        })
```

When I call the SetItemClickListener on the second recyclerView as well, then the whole process doesn't work.

It is very rare that there are two recyclerViews used so I haven't found anything either.

**EDIT**
I found the solution for my Problem:

I set the ImageView to a default picture, in case there is no URL.,

```
  if (!(lebensmittelList[position].fotoURL.isNullOrEmpty() || lebensmittelList[position].fotoURL.isNullOrBlank())) {
     .
     .
     .       GlideApp.with(this.context).load(fotoRef).into(holder.mProduktfoto)

        }else{

            holder.mProduktfoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_384_384)
        }
```